# How to display eck edit form in ctools modal or in other page?

Tags: database, entities

I need to display my custom eck edit form in ctools modal. How can I load the form I need in ctools modal or other page?

```
function edit_education_form_callback($ajax){
  if ($ajax) {
    ctools_include('ajax');
    ctools_include('modal');

    $form_state = array(
      'ajax' => TRUE,
      'title' => t('Education'),
    );

    $output = ctools_modal_form_wrapper('resume_education_edit_form', $form_state);

    if (!empty($form_state['executed'])) {
      // We'll just overwrite the form output if it was successful.
      $output = array();
      ctools_add_js('ajax-responder');
      if (isset($_GET['destination'])) {
        $output[] = ctools_modal_command_dismiss();
      }
      else {
        $output[] = ctools_ajax_command_redirect('my-account');
        drupal_set_message(t('successfully added.'));
        $output[] = ajax_command_after('.modal-title',theme('status_messages'));
      }
    }

    print ajax_render($output);
    drupal_exit();
  }
  else {
    return drupal_get_form('resume_education_edit_form');
  }
}

function resume_education_edit_form($form, &$form_state){
  // How can I call the eck edit form I created?
  // $output = ctools_modal_form_wrapper('eck_edit_form', $form_state)
  // Should I use drupal_get_form('eck__entity__edit')?
}
```

Comment: You can use the functions provided by the ctools module - where exactly are you stuck? Could you edit your code into the question please?

Comment: I am stuck in displaying the form,

Comment: Which ones have you tried? Which didn't work? Please remember this is a Q+A site, not a support forum - we're not here to do your work for you. Helping you with an interesting, well researched problem, though...that's what we're all about. For that we'll need to see your code and research efforts so far

Comment: Last try: please edit your question with all the relevant details that would help someone to understand what you're asking, what you've tried, and where it's failing. Dumping a single line of code into a comment does not exactly show an effort on your part, does it?

Comment: $output = ctools_modal_form_wrapper('eck_edit_form', $form_state); I tried to include the eck.entity.inc using module_load_include('inc', 'eck', 'eck.entity'); and call drupal_get_form('eck__entity__edit');

Comment: https://browse-tutorials.com/snippet/display-entity-construction-kit-eck-form-programmatically

Answer (score 1):

The right way to load the edit form of a custom entity bundle created with ECK is by using the `eck__entity__edit` function provided by the ECK module.

Usage example:

```
$output = eck__entity__edit($entity_type_name, $entity_bundle_name, $entity_id);
```

Comment: Thanks, @bmunslow, very helpful! I was trying this with drupal_get_form and drupal_build_form and was experiencing all sorts of problems. In order to get an add form, it is as easy as $output = eck__entity__add($entity_type_name, $entity_bundle_name);